# Highlight selected row

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I have a table view and I would like to highlight the selected cell on the users click how would I do this?

```
(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The "didSelect..." message is sent to the UITableViewDelegate (your class, *once the user has already selected* the row). So by the time you have gotten into that function, the row is selected. You do not manually need to select it. Note the description of the "didSelect..." function [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3adidSelectRowAtIndexPath%3a).

But you can select rows manually (in general) by sending [`selectRowAtIndexPath:animated:scrollPosition:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/selectRowAtIndexPath%3aanimated%3ascrollPosition%3a) to the table view.

You can find out more details from the [UITableView documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: sorry but i do not understand, do you have an example ?

Comment: +1 to counteract the -1: the answer is correct, don't downvote if you don't understand.

Comment: I edited my answer to provide more explicit links to the selectors in question. If your application is not showing a highlight, you may have other code elsewhere that is causing it to become deselected. You may need to look around more or post more code (possibly in a different question).

Answer (score 2):

When a user clicks on a cell, it is automatically highlighted. To unhighlight (as most apps do immediately (to get the 'button click' feel) ) you should use `-deselectRowAtIndexPath: animated:` as the first line in the `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` method.

Comment: but mine dosent show a highlight at all is it because i am using didselectrowatindexpath

Comment: No. If the cell receives the action (not a button over it or an accessory view or etc) it highlights *before* didSelectRowAtIndexPath: is even ran. It is part of the UITableViewController's job to do this.

Note: it is possible to have turned off this automatically highlighting in IB or in code for the specific cell.

Comment: then, as @Josh Petrie also pointed out, the problem is somewhere else in your code, where you have it deselecting or disallow deselecting, or like i said previously, have something else receiving the action (an invisible button or view for example). We can't magically find the problem without relevant code; nor do we want to try.